# SQLite sort by date

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, date

My date is in text format, as SQLite has no data type for date and time, so now I want to sort my data by date.

So when I query the database like

```
SELECT jobno, ondate FROM Reports ORDER BY DATE(ondate)
```

this will return the data sort alphabetically not by data. How would I sort by date?

Comment: Have you check `SELECT jobno, DATE(ondate) FROM Reports`? Probably `DATE()` is not being able to parse your data. Check supported formats in http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html Time Strings section.

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `ondate` column?

Comment: the format is dd/mm/YYYY

Comment: date should be in Long (milliseconds) format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SQLite compares/sorts strings of the form `dd/mm/YYYY`, it handles them like any other string, i.e., the first characters in the string have priority, e.g., `01/10/2013` is sorted before `22/01/2000`.

If you ever compare or sort dates, or use any of SQLite's [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you *must* use one of the supported date formats, like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

(In you particular query, you are calling the `DATE` function, which returns `NULL` if it does not recognize the format of its parameter. This means that your records were not sorted at all.)

Answer (score 3):

Either use Unix-epoch format, which is basically an INTEGER type, or time string (YYYY-MM-DD stuff).
A list of time string formats you can use can be found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Sort unix-epoch as you would sort an INTEGER type, and a time string as you would sort a TEXT type.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 things, to put your dates in milliseconds or use a text with the format YYYYMMDD.
Convert them every time you want to display them or you want to store them.
It's not complicated, and it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: `YYYYMMDD` is not a [supported date format](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: yepp my bad, it's YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Storing the date as a timestamp i.e in millisecond is a better option.